# CF and MO theories: seeing connections between the two approaches

Tags: quantum-chemistry, coordination-compounds, transition-metals

I wonder if and how when considering MO theory, we are accounting for the electrostatic interaction / repulsion between electrons on the metal and the ligand. It seems like MO assumes pure covalency, so why is this necessarily more accurate than crystal field?

I am primarily looking for a quantum mechanical explanation of what is accounted for when MOs are being constructed, but any suggestion or indication of the right direction would be great. Thank you!

Comment: I guess you're thinking about [Ligand field theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ligand_field_theory) not MO in general?

Comment: @Mithoron Yes, that's right!